# How to prevent Ajax redirects to another page in Asp.net Mvc 5

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have two forms in a single page.One of them is for adding comment, the other one is the main blog content as follows.

My aim is to have blog page with adding comment functionality.When user adds a comment , I want to post the comment another controller using ajax.When providing this functionality,I want user stay at the same page and update comments partial view at the page.However I couldn't achieve this with the codes below.

**Main Blog Content**

```
@model WforViolation.Models.Violation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}


<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
<p class="lead">
    Posted by @Model.CreatorUser.UserName<a href="#"></a>
</p>
<hr>
<!-- Date/Time -->
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on @Model.CreationDateTime <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> @Model.Severity Severity <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"> </span> @Model.Comments.Count Comments </p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> People Viewed</span></p>
<hr>
<!-- Preview Image -->
<img class="img-responsive" src="@Model.Picture.FirstOrDefault().MediumPath" alt="">
<hr>
<!-- Post Content -->
<p class="lead">@Model.Title</p>
<p>@Model.Description</p>

<hr>
<!-- Blog Comments -->
<!-- Comments Form -->
@Html.Partial("_AddComment", new WforViolation.Models.CommentViewModel() { ViolationId=Model.Id,Content=""})
<hr>
<!-- Posted Comments -->
<!-- Comment -->
@Html.Partial("_Comments",Model)
```

**Add Comment View**

```
@model WforViolation.Models.CommentViewModel
<div class="well">
    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComment", "Comment", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "SuccessMessage",
        OnFailure = "FailMessage"
        //UpdateTargetId = "resultTarget"
    }, new { id = "MyNewNameId", role = "form" })) // set new Id name for  Form
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @rows = 3 })
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ViolationId)
    }
    </div>
<script>
    //\\\\\\\ JS  retrun message SucccessPost or FailPost
    function SuccessMessage() {
        alert("Succcess Post");
    }
    function FailMessage() {
        alert("Fail Post");
    }
</script>
```

**My Comment Controller**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddComment(CommentViewModel commentViewModel)
    {
         Comment comment = new Comment();
         var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID))
        {
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
            var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            comment.ApplicationUser=currentUser;
        }
        var violationId = commentViewModel.ViolationId;
        Violation violationCommentedOn = context.Violations.Where(x => x.Id == violationId).FirstOrDefault();
        comment.Violation = violationCommentedOn;
        context.Comments.Add(comment);
        context.SaveChanges();
        var result = Json(
                       new
                       {
                           Success = true,//success
                           StatusMessage = "Object created successfully"
                       });
        return result;
    }
```

When I added a comment it redirects me to another page called localhost/Comment/AddComment its content is just the Json. 
Is it ever possible to just retrieve JsonResult and stay at the same page ?

Or I cant post a form data using ajax and not redirecting to another page?

I know there are similar questions but I couldn't find the exact answer.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Form in your Add Comment view and that form calls AddComment in your controller that returns a json data.  Forms do cause a redirect to the method they call and because your controller is returning json, the browser simply displays it on a new page.

You may either return a view from your AddComment method in the controller. This view could be the comment view.  This way the control will redirect back to the same view with new data. This is a sample code, in practice, this code should be pretty much the same as you may have it in ShowAddCommentView method of the controller.

```
CommentViewModel commentVM; 
/// populate commentVM from DB or comment store
/// remove return result;
return View("AddCommentView", commentVM);  /// your add comment view name
```

Or instead of using Form to send data to the controller, use a simple ajax call without using AjaxForm.  When a user clicks on the button, you can call Ajax in javascript.  I have a jquery example.  parameter1, parameter2 are the same as properties of your CommentViewModel.  Of course, you can also use json data parameter in this call instead passing parameters like in this following sample.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Comment/AddComment?parameter1='+ pvalue1 + '&parameter2=' + pvalue2,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (msg) {
            /// this msg object is actually the json object your controller is returning. 
        }
    });
```

This call will not cause the page to redirect. When json is returned, you may write code in javascript to do something with that data, perhaps display it back on the add comment page.

It is possible to make this ajax call from asp.net directly without using a separate javascript. But I can't seem to remember it exactly right now.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Using `Ajax.BeginForm()` which will stay on the same page if you have included the relevant `jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js` file in the view. If you do not include the script, then `Ajax.BeginForm()` acts as `Html.BeginForm()` which is why your redirecting.

Comment: @Stephen Adding jquery-unobstrusive-ajax.js and not changing anything else will not work because then it will appear to the user as if nothing happened upon submit. The return result from the controller call needs to be displayed someway, which can either be redirect to the same view or calling ajax and displaying return result.

Comment: Yes, but that can be done in the `OnSuccess` and `OnFailure` callbacks (as OP is using) or by using the `UpdateTargetId` option to update the DOM if a partial view is returned.

Comment: @Stephen you are right.jquery-unobstrusive-ajax.js has to be   included to prevent redirecting.By the way I realized that I forgot to include it.However,@Allen tried to show ways to update comments without redirect to same view or any other view